# Java Regular Expressions for unknown equation

Tags: java, regex, expression

I am trying to use a single line, no space equation as input but am new to regex.  I know the regex in my code are completely wrong but it is the best way to explain what i am trying to do. some example cases would be 12+2=14, -4+54=50, 5*8=40, 8--2=10, 2-4=-6 etc. I would also really appreciate it if someone could tell me how to have an OR in regular expressions because I could not find any info.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = sc.next();

    String re1="((-)(\\d+))|(\\d+)";    // -int1 or int1
    String re2="((\\+) | - | (\\*))";   //+ or - or *
    String re3="((-)(\\d+))|(\\d+)";    // -int2 or int2
    String re4="(=)";                   // Equals
    String re5="((-)(\\d+))|(\\d+)";    // -int3 or int3

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    if (matcher.find()) {

        String int1 = matcher.group(2);
        String op1 = matcher.group(3);
        String int2 = matcher.group(4);
        String op2 = matcher.group(5);
        String int3 = matcher.group(6);
        System.out.println(int1 + " " + op2 + " " + int2 + " " + op2 + " " + int3);
    }
}
```

Comment: `or` is single `|`...

Comment: Thats what I thought but when I tried it it didn't work.

Comment: and you don't need space around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I suggest using a website like http://www.regexr.com/ to test your regular expressions live.

Then, instead of an "OR" you can use the optional quantifier, e.g. `([-]?\d+)` matches any negative and positive number:
`[-]` is a set containing the minus sign, the following `?` means that set can occur zero or one time (that's why it is called optional quantifier), then `\d+` means a digit occuring one or more times.

To sepcify the operators you can use the set `[+\-*\/]`. Note that `-` must be escaped by a `\` in this case because normally when found in a set like `[a-n]` it stands for a range between `a` and `n`. But in our case it is just part of a set.

So, taking this two parts you can would end up with a regex like this: `([-]?\d+)([+\-*/])([-]?\d+)=([-]?\d+)`

Note that you must escape the `\` inside a Java string (which I haven't done here because its mainly about the regex).